# How do I extract the ANOVA table for variable importance in kmeans clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I performed K-means clustering in R to profile customers with different spending behaviours. Now that I got the clusters and want to get the ANOVA table indicates which variables contribute the most to my cluster solution in R. How can I do so?

I've seen that this can be done in SPSS but not so sure how to do it in R.
Here is a tutorial on how this can be done in SPSS: https://arifkamarbafadal.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/ebook-037-tutorial-spss-k-means-cluster-analysis.pdf

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @user11558061 Do you know any example that makes this calculation ANOVA step by step? Hand made.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly did you get stuck?